Make field Readonly for certain Groups in Odoo 17
I want to make pricelist_id field in Sales Order Read only for a new_group and pricelist_id is already having a group product.group_product_pricelist for the version 17. I have tried below code but its not making Pricelist field Read only for the users having new_group.

    
                

    1
    new_module.new_group, !product.group_product_pricelist
`

Please use this:
readonly="'group_id' in '[group_name.group.name]'"

